# O que estou fazendo de errado? (struct)

Tags: c

```
struct book{
    char code[5];
    char title[30];
    char category[15];
    char author[30];
    float price;
};

struct book book[100];
book[0].price = 1;
```

Está dando erro na última linha

Comment: Não vejo problemas: http://ideone.com/Aps1ic

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa da palavra *struct* na declaração da variável.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    struct book{
        char code[5];
        char title[30];
        char category[15];
        char author[30];
        float price;
    };

    book books[100];
    books[0].price = 1.0;
    printf("%f/n" ,books[0].price);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente declarar da seguinte forma sua struct:

```
struct book{
char code[5]; 
char title[30]; 
char category[15]; 
char author[30]; 
float price; 
}sBook;

sbook book[100]; 
book[0].price = 1;
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver altere o nome do vetor, por exemplo, para books.

```
struct book books[100];
```

Depois ao atribuir o valor 1 a um float faça assim:

```
books[0].price = 1.0;
```